# How to add or update new value from temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to update row if exist A,B,Tarih and  Not exist how to insert?

My original Code:

```
 Insert X(A,B,C,D,E,Tarih)
select substring(dosya,2,25) as A, 
substring(dosya,27,15) as B,
substring(dosya,70,40) as C,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),substring(dosya,52,17)) as D,
case when substring(dosya,124,2)='00' then 'TL'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='01' then 'USD'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='02' then 'CHF'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='03' then 'CAD'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='04' then 'KWD'

     when substring(dosya,124,2)='05' then 'GBP'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='06' then 'SAR'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='07' then 'JPY'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='08' then 'EUR'

     when substring(dosya,124,2)='09' then 'AUD'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='10' then 'IRR'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='11' then 'DK'
     when substring(dosya,124,2)='12' then 'SEK'
 else 'Döviz' end  as E,
@tarih as Tarih
 from #TempLog
```

i want to update existing value

Pseudo code :

```
if exist ( A,B,C in BankaEntegrasyonLog)

{

       Update Row!

}

else

{

 Insert 

X(A,B,C,D,E,Tarih)

select substring(dosya,2,25) as   . . . . .  

}
```

Comment: You need the `merge` command.  I would suggest you look it up in the SQL Server documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the MERGE statement.

First, let's create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestLog( SomeKey INTEGER, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
```

And we can insert some values into it:

```
INSERT INTO TestLog( SomeKey, SomeAttribute ) VALUES ( 43, 'Something' );
INSERT INTO TestLog( SomeKey, SomeAttribute ) VALUES ( 55, 'Another' );
INSERT INTO TestLog( SomeKey, SomeAttribute ) VALUES ( 77, 'Demo' );
```

Now, let's use MERGE with a key that already exists. If we should update 'Something' to 'updated!' for SomeKey = 43:

```
MERGE TestLog AS TARGET
USING (SELECT 43 AS SomeKey, 'Updated!' AS SomeAttribute)
AS SOURCE( SomeKey, SomeAttribute )
ON (TARGET.SomeKey = SOURCE.SomeKey )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET SomeAttribute = Source.SomeAttribute
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (SomeKey, SomeAttribute)
   VALUES (SOURCE.SomeKey, SOURCE.SomeAttribute);
```

We can check that it worked:

SELECT * FROM TestLog WHERE SomeKey = 43;

and we indeed see "Updated!" for SomeAttribute. We can try a new value:

```
MERGE TestLog AS TARGET
USING (SELECT 22 AS SomeKey, 'Newone!' AS SomeAttribute)
AS SOURCE( SomeKey, SomeAttribute )
ON (TARGET.SomeKey = SOURCE.SomeKey )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET SomeAttribute = Source.SomeAttribute
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (SomeKey, SomeAttribute)
   VALUES (SOURCE.SomeKey, SOURCE.SomeAttribute);
```

And to check it:

```
SELECT * FROM TestLog;
```

We indeed see a new fourth row with (22, 'Newone!'). It shouldn't be hard to expand this example to your specific table and insert pattern. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
MERGE [dbo].[X] AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING([dosya],2,25) AS [A],
        SUBSTRING([dosya],27,15) AS [B],
        SUBSTRING([dosya],70,40) AS [C],
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),SUBSTRING([dosya],52,17)) AS [D],
        CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='00' THEN 'TL'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='01' THEN 'USD'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='02' THEN 'CHF'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='03' THEN 'CAD'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='04' THEN 'KWD'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='05' THEN 'GBP'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='06' THEN 'SAR'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='07' THEN 'JPY'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='08' THEN 'EUR'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='09' THEN 'AUD'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='10' THEN 'IRR'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='11' THEN 'DK'
            WHEN SUBSTRING([dosya],124,2)='12' THEN 'SEK'
            ELSE 'Döviz'
        END AS [E],
        @tarih AS [Tarih]
    FROM #TempLog
) AS SOURCE
    ON SOURCE.[A] = TARGET.[A]
    AND SOURCE.[B] = TARGET.[B]
    AND SOURCE.[Tarih] = TARGET.[Tarih]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        [A],
        [B],
        [C],
        [D],
        [E],
        [Tarih]
    )
    VALUES (
        SOURCE.[A],
        SOURCE.[B],
        SOURCE.[C],
        SOURCE.[D],
        SOURCE.[E],
        SOURCE.[Tarih]
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET [C] = SOURCE.[C],
        [D] = SOURCE.[D],
        [E] = SOURCE.[E];
```

I would also consider creating a lookup table to replace that case statement. This might make future maintenance easier.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sel_mrtg_bankaentegrasyondosyaolustur, Line 772
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sel_mrtg_bankaentegrasyondosyaolustur, Line 797
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

according to recommendations Gordon Linoff

```
MERGE X AS target
USING
 (
  select Id,
         substring(dosya,2,25) as A,
         substring(dosya,27,15) as B,
         substring(dosya,70,40) as C,
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),substring(dosya,52,17)) as D,
         case when substring(dosya,124,2)='00' then 'TL'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='01' then 'USD'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='02' then 'CHF'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='03' then 'CAD'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='04' then 'KWD'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='05' then 'GBP'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='06' then 'SAR'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='07' then 'JPY'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='08' then 'EUR'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='09' then 'AUD'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='10' then 'IRR'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='11' then 'DK'
              when substring(dosya,124,2)='12' then 'SEK'
              else 'Döviz' end  as TutarParaBrimi, @tarih as Tarih
  from #TempLog
  ) AS source
ON target.Id = source.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET A = source.A,
             B = source.B,
             C = source.C,
             D = source.D,
             E = source.E,
             Tarih = source.Tarih
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (A, B, C, D, E, Tarih)
  VALUES (source.A, source.B, source.C, source.D, source.E, source.Tarih);
```

If you don't have Id column then replace target.Id = source.Id on
     A = source.A 
     AND target.B = source.B
     AND target.C = source.C
     AND target.D = source.D
     AND target.E = source.E
     AND target.Tarih = source.Tarih